# Windows on a partition BSOD's within a minute of startup after Windows Update

Tags: imac, bootcamp, windows, driver

iMac, 27 inch, mid 2011, 3.1 GHz Quad Core i5, AMD Radeon HD 6970M

BSOD error message: SYSTEM_THREAD_EXCEPTION_NOT_HANDLED (igdkmd64.sys)

From what I've read elsewhere this seems to be an issue with the Intel Integrated Graphics Driver (Intel HD 4000) But disabling the driver still causes the bug because igdkmd64.sys is still present. At one point I had deleted igdkmd64.sys and disabled the driver which stopped crashing but videos wouldn't play either. The two might or might not be related.

Has anyone else had this problem and found a solution to it?

Comment: This sounds like it belongs on a PC-specific section.  The only thing Apple about this is your hardware.  Maybe http://superuser.com/

Comment: I thought this would be the best place for it though since it seems to be a hardware (or at least hardware/driver interaction) problem

Answer (score 1):

At first glance, I am wondering why you are using an HD 4000 driver for an AMD Radeon HD 6970M chip.

Have you tried downloading and installing the AMD Drivers?

http://www.amd.com/en-us/products/graphics/desktop/6000/6970

Comment: The Radeon Driver is also installed, in fact it is installed from the start, the Intel Driver then gets added by windows update and that causes the BSOD's

Comment: Can you boot into "Safe Mode" and manually change the driver?

Answer (score 0):

I have this problem with imac12's and macmini7's.  I suspect it's a similar problem to the usb series 7 and series 8 drivers bluescreening each other, even though the hardware id matches.